# When redirecting my pages with a .htaccess file, my sessions do not travel between altered pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, session

I have a login system on a website of mine that requires the user to login with an email and password. The login system works, however when setting the session it only works with links such as:

"https://www.website.com/account.php"

...and doesn't work with the modified links such as:

"https://www.website.com/account/"

I have tried to fix this by looking through multiple online resources and trying my best to get familiar with htaccess files and sessions, however I'm afraid that i'm still very much so a novice in those 2 areas.

I picked up a while back some .htaccess code which works for multiple websites that I've created:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

If there is anything wrong here that would cause my Sessions to not load throughout the redirected pages, I'd like to change it so it would work with both of the types of links:

"https://www.example.com/account/" 
and
"https://www.example.com/account.php"

Here is my Session code:

```
//login user
$_SESSION['example_id'] = $row["exampleUser"];
$_SESSION['example_displayName'] = $row["exampleDisplay"];
$_SESSION['example_email'] = $row["exampleEmail"];
$_SESSION['example_pass'] = $row["examplePass"];
header("Location: https://www.example.net/account/");
exit();
```

Comment: Can you please show your session code? Is the session being started before anything?

Comment: Check what path gets specified when the session id cookie gets set. With `/account.php` and `/foobar.php` you have been operating on the same URL folder level so far, but if you change those to `/account/` and `/ foobar/`, that’s now two different “folders” - so if the session id cookie was accidentally set for the current folder only, that would make it fail at this point.

Comment: I updated the post to include my code which logs the user in.